# how to hide all inactive/disable steps in magento checkout page

Tags: javascript, php, magento

I want to show only one step at a time on magento checkout page. When a customer will click on continue button then next step should appear and remaining all steps should be hidden.
As you can see in the picture, checkout method is active and remaining steps are just disabled. So here I want all disabled steps to be hidden instead.
There are two `js` files included: `accordion.js` and `opcheckout.js`. I tried a lot to achieve this but I couldn't. Help me, please !!

[image: here is screenshot of my checkout page]

Comment: Mind sharing the HTML/JS/CSS with us?  Maybe show it on a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Answer (score 0):

```
.opc .step-title {
    display: none;
}
```

add this in your css.

[image: result screen shot]
the titles for step will be hidden as marked in image.

So if you want to display the current step title you need to write in your respective template file.

Comment: yeah its look good idea, BUT  how can i show current active title

Comment: told you before in my answer. there are template files for each step. so you need to write html code their having the text for current step title